# How to use vue material in a project

Tags: vuejs2, vue-material

I am trying to implement [vue-material](https://vuematerial.io/getting-started) in my laravel v.5.5 project, I have installed the package, and I am importing the js part in my `app.js` and css file in my sass file like it says in the docs:

**App.js**

```
window.Vue = require('vue');

import VueMaterial from 'vue-material';
Vue.use(VueMaterial);
```

**App.scss**

```
@import '~vue-material/dist/vue-material.min.css';
```

I am trying to implement the `vue-material` [app componen](https://vuematerial.io/components/app)t just to test it in the vue `example-component`:

```
<template>
  <div class="page-container">
    <md-app md-waterfall md-mode="fixed-last">
      <md-app-toolbar class="md-large md-dense md-primary">
        <div class="md-toolbar-row">
          <div class="md-toolbar-section-start">
            <md-button class="md-icon-button" @click="menuVisible = !menuVisible">
              <md-icon>menu</md-icon>
            </md-button>

            <span class="md-title">My Title</span>
          </div>

          <div class="md-toolbar-section-end">
            <md-button class="md-icon-button">
              <md-icon>more_vert</md-icon>
            </md-button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="md-toolbar-row">
          <md-tabs class="md-primary">
            <md-tab id="tab-home" md-label="Home"></md-tab>
            <md-tab id="tab-pages" md-label="Pages"></md-tab>
            <md-tab id="tab-posts" md-label="Posts"></md-tab>
            <md-tab id="tab-favorites" md-label="Favorites"></md-tab>
          </md-tabs>
        </div>
      </md-app-toolbar>

      <md-app-drawer :md-active.sync="menuVisible">
        <md-toolbar class="md-transparent" md-elevation="0">Navigation</md-toolbar>

        <md-list>
          <md-list-item>
            <md-icon>move_to_inbox</md-icon>
            <span class="md-list-item-text">Inbox</span>
          </md-list-item>

          <md-list-item>
            <md-icon>send</md-icon>
            <span class="md-list-item-text">Sent Mail</span>
          </md-list-item>

          <md-list-item>
            <md-icon>delete</md-icon>
            <span class="md-list-item-text">Trash</span>
          </md-list-item>

          <md-list-item>
            <md-icon>error</md-icon>
            <span class="md-list-item-text">Spam</span>
          </md-list-item>
        </md-list>
      </md-app-drawer>

      <md-app-content>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Error quibusdam, non molestias et! Earum magnam, similique, quo recusandae placeat dicta asperiores modi sint ea repudiandae maxime? Quae non explicabo, neque.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Error quibusdam, non molestias et! Earum magnam, similique, quo recusandae placeat dicta asperiores modi sint ea repudiandae maxime? Quae non explicabo, neque.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Error quibusdam, non molestias et! Earum magnam, similique, quo recusandae placeat dicta asperiores modi sint ea repudiandae maxime? Quae non explicabo, neque.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Error quibusdam, non molestias et! Earum magnam, similique, quo recusandae placeat dicta asperiores modi sint ea repudiandae maxime? Quae non explicabo, neque.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Error quibusdam, non molestias et! Earum magnam, similique, quo recusandae placeat dicta asperiores modi sint ea repudiandae maxime? Quae non explicabo, neque.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Error quibusdam, non molestias et! Earum magnam, similique, quo recusandae placeat dicta asperiores modi sint ea repudiandae maxime? Quae non explicabo, neque.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Error quibusdam, non molestias et! Earum magnam, similique, quo recusandae placeat dicta asperiores modi sint ea repudiandae maxime? Quae non explicabo, neque.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Error quibusdam, non molestias et! Earum magnam, similique, quo recusandae placeat dicta asperiores modi sint ea repudiandae maxime? Quae non explicabo, neque.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Error quibusdam, non molestias et! Earum magnam, similique, quo recusandae placeat dicta asperiores modi sint ea repudiandae maxime? Quae non explicabo, neque.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Error quibusdam, non molestias et! Earum magnam, similique, quo recusandae placeat dicta asperiores modi sint ea repudiandae maxime? Quae non explicabo, neque.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Error quibusdam, non molestias et! Earum magnam, similique, quo recusandae placeat dicta asperiores modi sint ea repudiandae maxime? Quae non explicabo, neque.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Error quibusdam, non molestias et! Earum magnam, similique, quo recusandae placeat dicta asperiores modi sint ea repudiandae maxime? Quae non explicabo, neque.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Error quibusdam, non molestias et! Earum magnam, similique, quo recusandae placeat dicta asperiores modi sint ea repudiandae maxime? Quae non explicabo, neque.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Error quibusdam, non molestias et! Earum magnam, similique, quo recusandae placeat dicta asperiores modi sint ea repudiandae maxime? Quae non explicabo, neque.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Error quibusdam, non molestias et! Earum magnam, similique, quo recusandae placeat dicta asperiores modi sint ea repudiandae maxime? Quae non explicabo, neque.</p>
      </md-app-content>
    </md-app>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    menuVisible: false
  })
}
</script>
```

I am then using the component in the blade view like this:

How can I fix this?

```
@section('content')
 <example-component></example-component>
@endsection
```

But, the nav is not fixed at all and the drawer is not working, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does your browser console log say? There must be something error msg..